systemd doesn't work nicely with pdflatex
I wrote a program that should be run as a service, so I wrote a systemd units file and tried it out, but pdflatex (which is called by my program) keeps throwing errors since some directory settings are misconfigured (for example TEXMFHOME is "./texmf" instead of "/root/texmf").  This issue I was able to resolve by symlinking texmf, but now it can't find some fonts.  Instead of trying to work around that too, I decided I should address the root issue:  Why is pdflatex behaving differently when called by systemd compared to when called directly (which works perfectly, even though it's the same user – root both times).
I don't know how to search for an solution, so I'm asking here.
Thanks!

PS: Due to some bug in stack exchange, I can't write comments and can't click on "Show … more comments", so don't be surprised if I don't answer or even acknowledge you.
"Comments":

@JaromandaX: "Yes, obviously something is misconfigured, the question is how and how to fix it."


Perhaps you've misconfigured the systemd file
